# How to Interface 16 * 2 LCD(HD44780) using Verilog to FPGA/CPLD?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, system-verilog, intel-fpga

I want to interface a [16 character * 2 line LCD (HD44780)](http://www.wvshare.com/product/LCD1602-blue.htm) to my FPGA board using Verilog HDL. The program I wrote does not work at all and I don't know why, even though I made a state machine and inserted delays. Note that I used 8 bit mode. Here is my code:

```
module lcd(input wire clk,output reg [7:0]data,output reg rs,output reg rw ,output reg enb);        
wire sclk;//Slow Clock for Giving 450 ns Wide Delay
reg [3:0]state=4'b0000;
reg [3:0]next_state;
sender send(clk,sclk);  //Instance of Counter For Generating Delay

always@(sclk)
begin
state=next_state;
end

//Always First Block thant Handles flow of Our state machines means Always Second block//
//Always Second Block For State Machine of Our 16 * 2 LCD///////////////////////////////    

always@(state)
begin
////////////////These State are For LCD Commands////////////////
enb=1'b0;

case(state)

4'b0000:begin    //Do Noting because this state waste in Initialization of "state" variable..
next_state=4'b0001;
end         


4'b0001:begin    //Using LCD Command 0X38(00111000)
rs=1'b0;
rw=1'b0;
data=8'b00111000;
enb=1'b1; //Logic is Sending High(1) then uses clocks Delay then Low(0) of Next state..
next_state=4'b0010;
end      

4'b0010:begin   //Using LCD Command 0X0E(00001110)
rs=1'b0;
rw=1'b0;
data=8'b00001110;   
enb=1'b1; //Logic is Sending High(1) then uses clocks Delay then Low(0) of Next state..
next_state=4'b0011;
end


4'b0011:begin   //Using LCD Command 0X01(00000001)
rs=1'b0;
rw=1'b0;
data=8'b00000001;   
enb=1'b1; //Logic is Sending High(1) then uses clocks Delay then Low(0) of Next state..
next_state=4'b0100;
end

4'b0100:begin   //Using LCD Command 0X06(00000110)
rs=1'b0;
rw=1'b0;
data=8'b00000110;
enb=1'b1; //Logic is Sending High(1) then uses clocks Delay then Low(0) of Next state..
next_state=4'b0110; 
end



////////////These State Are for LCD Data////////////////////

4'b0110:begin    //Using LCD "S" Having Value
rs=1'b1;
rw=1'b0;
data=8'b01010111;
enb=1'b1; //Logic is Sending High(1) then uses clocks Delay then Low(0) of Next state..
next_state=4'b0110;
end




endcase
end


endmodule
```

This is the code of its instance "Sender":

```
module sender(input wire clkin,output reg clkout);
 reg [19:0]tmp=20'b00000_00000_00000_00000;

//Always Block for Greater than 450ns wide delay Generation////////

always@(posedge clkin)
 begin 
  tmp = tmp+1'b1;
  clkout=tmp[19]; 
 end        

 endmodule
```

Please check this code on your boards. I tried it on my "DIGIASIC Altera Cyclone II board", which has an [EP2C8Q208C8 fpga](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyc2/cyc2_cii5v1.pdf). I also tried lower and higher delays in the sender instance, but none worked.

Comment: Have you simulated it?  The Altera tools come with a free edition of ModelSim.

Comment: yes sir I had already simulate in many simulator including Modelsim , ALDEC's Active-HDL & in Synapticad's Verilogger Extreame...it works well in these simulators....

Comment: Show some simulated waveforms.  And a link to the LCD driver datasheet.  Make it *easy* for people to help you.

Comment: Rather than saying it does not work, can you be more specific as to what is the problem?

Comment: Sir I don't know what is the problem ..Actually Sir for LCD Interfacing we must keep two things in mind first is the Delay and the other is Initialization of LCD but I had already do this....

Answer (score -1):

There are many more timing requirements than you have implemented in your code. You need to look carefully at the datasheet for your LCD module. Be aware that it takes the LCD module many *microseconds* to execute a command...your 450 ns delay is not nearly enough.

Comment: What more timing requirement sir? can you explain me ...sir according to you I have to increase the delay.....? please explain me so that I make change in my code...please